# Why am I not able to import the following File

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This is my src directory -

[image]

And while importing the last file (StateProvider.js) in Product.js, this is the error I get while importing StateProvider -

[image]

My import statement from Product.js-

[image]

Can anyone guide me, why my import is not working?

Comment: I don't see any `StateProvider.js` file at the same location as `Products.js`

Comment: It even prints in the error message the exact location where it is looking for the file. Did you ever read the whole message and check the location it mentioned to see if the file was loaded from the correct folder?

Answer (score 4):

The error occurs because `StateProvider.js` is not in the same directory as `Product.js`. You have to specify the import statement like this:

`import StateProvider from '../../StateProvider';`

Answer (score 1):

Probably 2 errors.

First, If you export the default file you're good to go.

```
export default StateProvider
```

Second is if you are on the correct directory.

it shouild be

```
import StateProvider from '../../StateProvider'
```

Comment: Yeah I had written the export statement, thank you so much, this works

Comment: Should be accepted as anwer.✌️

Answer (score 0):

```
import StateProvider from '../../StateProvider'
```

I also recommend using "Auto Import" extension if you working with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: This answer was already given by PAUL.